# Add/hide blocks on user page

Tags: blocks

I have some blocks for navigation and side bars that are appearing all over the site.

I want to hide the navigation and sidebars on the following urls:

```
node/78
node/19
user
messages
```

For some reason, drupal will hide the nav and side bars on node/78 and node/19 but not the user and messages pages.   How do I make it disappear from the user and messages page as well?

What I've done so far was click on Structure>Block, then go to the block I want, configure it, and list the paths for the blocks I want to hide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your solution here is to also include `user/*` and `messages/*` in your list.

So the whole list would read:

```
node/78
node/19
user
user/*
messages
messages/*
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like `user` and `messages` aren't even necessary. Just include `user/*` and `messages/*` in your list on that block's configuration page.